# Polymorphic variant, and binding a reference of one type to a reference of another

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been experimenting with a class that I call `PolymorphicVariant`, which is pretty much like a `unique_ptr` except it stores its value inline instead of allocating it on the heap. For this I used a `variant` type (a home-made version) and some static asserts to check that all variants implement a given interface (i.e. that they all derive from the same base class). I then have methods to get a pointer to the base class. I can then store `PolymorphicVariant`s in containers and have it act the same way as if I was storing pointers to the base class, except there's no indirection.

```
template <typename Base, typename... Derivees>
class PolymorphicVariant {
    static_assert(std::is_polymorphic<Base>{},
                  "Base type has to be polymorphic");

    static_assert(meta::And<std::is_base_of<Base, Derivees>...>{},
                  "Derivees have to derive from Base");

    using VariantType = Variant<Derivees...>;
    using Types = meta::List<Derivees...>;

    struct ToBasePtrVisitor {
        template <typename T>
        auto operator()(const T& value) const -> const Base* {
            return &value;
        }
    };

public:
    // ... Constructors and assignment operators ...

    auto get() const -> const Base* {
        return apply(ToBasePtrVisitor{}, m_storage);
    }

private:
    VariantType m_storage;
};
```

I can then do stuff like this:

```
// Bar and Baz both implement IFoo
using Foo = PolymorphicVariant<IFoo, Bar, Baz>;

std::vector<Foo> foos;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        foos.emplace_back(Bar{});
    } else {
        foos.emplace_back(Baz{});
    }
}

for (const auto& elem : foos) {
    elem.get()->some_virtual_fn();
}
```

So now to my problem. Let's say I have a function that takes a reference to a `PolymorphicVariant` (as you would with a function taking a pointer to an abstract base class):

```
auto mutate_foo(Foo& foo) -> void {
    foo.get()->mutating_function();
}

Bar my_bar;
mutate_foo(my_bar); // This doesn't work
```

The reason this doesn't work is I can't bind a reference of `Bar` to a reference of `Foo` (i.e. `PolymorphicVariant<IFoo, Bar, Baz>`). Is there any way to make this possible? Some way to tell the compiler that a `Bar` reference can actually be treated as a `Foo` reference? Without changing the implementation of either `IFoo` or `Bar`. If it isn't possible, I'd have to instead change the signature of `mutate_foo` to `mutate_foo(IFoo* foo) -> void`, but this feels less clean as I'd want `Foo` to act like the preferred type to use to mean "thing that contains something that fulfills an interface IFoo". Thanks!

Comment: The common interface is `Base`. A `Foo` is not a `Bar` so passing a Bar when the function requires a Foo is not appropriate.

Comment: Why not instead give the variant an implicit conversion to the base type, and make `mutate_foo` also take a reference to the base type?

Comment: I agree with Richard: you can mutate `Foo& foo` to store a `Baz` instead, which breaks the caller who supplied a `Bar my_bar`.

Comment: @RichardHodges Hmm, I guess what I wanted to communicate is that `Bar` actually could be considered a `Foo`, as if `Foo` was a base class of `Bar` without actually being a base class. If that makes sense. I think I might go with what @KerrekSB suggested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

Here:

```
auto mutate_foo(Foo& foo) -> void {
  foo.get()->mutating_function();
}
```

create a type `FooRef`.

```
auto mutate_foo(FooRef foo) -> void {
  foo.get()->mutating_function();
}
```

`FooRef` is based off of `PolymorphicAnyRef`.  `PolymorphicAnyRef` is much like your `PolymorphicVariant`, but it instead stores a *pointer* to the things that derives from `Base` and a way to get a `Base*` from that pointer.

A simple implementation is to simply store a `Base*` and have `get()` return it.

```
template<class Base>
struct PolymorphicAnyRef {
  Base* ptr = 0;
  Base* get() const { return ptr; }
  // blah, etc

  template<class T>
  PolymorphicAnyRef( T& t ): ptr(std::addressof(t)) {}
  template<class...Ts>
  PolymorphicAnyRef( PolymorphicVariant<Base, Ts...>& pv ):
    ptr( pv.get() )
  {}
};
```

This adds some syntactic sugar over taking a `Base*` in that it converts from anything derived-from `Base` or any reference-to `PolymorphicVariant<Base,???>`.

As an aside, instead of `PolymorphicVariant`, I'd write a `PolymorphicAny<Base, Ts...>` which is guaranteed to store any of `Ts...` but also can store anything *smaller than* and *less aligned* the `Ts...` that is sufficiently "regular" (copyable, whatever else you require).  Have the derived-check be done at construction instead of at type instantiation.

It could then store a function pointer to convert the `void*` to the stored interior `Any` to a `Base*`, and use it for `get()`.  A well writen `super_any` that supports adding new type erasure methods would let you store that operaiton along with the default ones.

But I'm a bit nuts.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make this possible? Without changing the implementation of either `IFoo` or `Bar`.

I cannot think of any way of doing that right now. I'll edit my post if I can think of a (good) one.

---

> I'd want `Foo` to act like the preferred type to use to mean "thing that contains something that fulfills an interface `IFoo`".

You can use a `template` function:

```
template <typename TFoo>
auto mutate_foo(TFoo& foo) -> void {
    foo.get()->mutating_function();
}
```

You might want to constrain it with a predicate that checks whether ot not `TFoo` is actually implementing your desired interface:

```
template <typename TFoo, 
          typename std::enable_if_t<implements_foo_interface<TFoo>{}>>
auto mutate_foo(TFoo& foo) -> void {
    foo.get()->mutating_function();
}
```

`implements_foo_interface` can be implemented easily using the [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, it occurred to me that there is no need for `Foo` and `Bar` to inherit from a common interface. variant visitors already provide the plumbing to find the correct method if you supply a free function overload in the namespaces of `Foo` and `Bar`.

example (using `boost::variant`, as I don't have access to your library):

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void do_something() { std::cout << "something\n"; }
};


struct Bar {
    // note - dissimilar interfaces
    void do_something_else() { std::cout << "something else\n"; }
};


void mutating_function(Foo& on) {
    // overload explicit actions here
    on.do_something();
}

void mutating_function(Bar& on) {
    // overload explicit actions here
    on.do_something_else();
}

struct invoke_mutating_function
{
    template<class Target>
    void operator()(Target& on) const {
        mutating_function(on);
    }
};


using FooBar = boost::variant<Foo, Bar>;

void mutating_function(FooBar& on)
{
    boost::apply_visitor(invoke_mutating_function(), on);
}

int main()
{
    FooBar x = Foo();
    FooBar y = Bar();

    mutating_function(x);
    mutating_function(y);

}
```

expected output:

```
something
something else
```